# Pandas Use a column consists of column names to populate the values dynamically into another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to obtain the 'Value' column below, from the original df:

```
    A   B   C   Column_To_Use
0   2   3   4   A            
1   5   6   7   C            
2   8   0   9   B            


    A   B   C   Column_To_Use   Value       
0   2   3   4   A               2
1   5   6   7   C               7
2   8   0   9   B               0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['Value'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Column_To_Use'])
print (df)
   A  B  C Column_To_Use  Value
0  2  3  4             A      2
1  5  6  7             C      7
2  8  0  9             B      0
```